# How to use pipenv shell ? I'm getting an Error

Tags: pipenv

I typed this on cmd

```
pipenv shell
```

but it says an error like this

```
Usage: pipenv shell [OPTIONS] [SHELL_ARGS]...

ERROR:: --system is intended to be used for pre-existing Pipfile installation, not installation of specific packages. Aborting.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type:  `python3 -m pipenv shell`

The `-m` option stands for module.  The above tells Python to execute the `pipenv` module, and `shell` is a parameter to `pipenv` that tells it to switch to the virtual environment.  To exit the venv and get back to the regular bash shell, just type `exit`.

As an aside, the above is distinct from doing Python command line operations on your Django project, e.g., after the virtual environment is activated by the above commands, you can then use the Django management command `python3 manage.py shell` to open a Python command line in order to work on your Django project.  This Django management command opens the Python shell with all of your Django project settings, models, etc. available.

Comment: Thanks ,finally it worked. love you <3000